# Pick day but show also week number

Tags: javascript, html

I have a day select input field: `<input type="date">`.

When I click this to select the date, I would like to have a week number info shown like this (see the WEEK info on the left:

[image]

I tried to use `<input type="week">`, but that's not a solution for me, as I still need to select single days.

I can't use jquery here, only plain javascript.

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: @Wimanicesir no library. Its just plain html so far

Comment: So it's the standard date picker? That is only gonna works on your OS + Browser :) So I would advise you to look to another solution because it's not going to render as you want on other browers :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir thats okay, its for our company, we all have the same os + browser (forced). Yes its the standard date picker.

Comment: Ok in that case: Check selected month. Loop each monday to get number of the week and prepend this. (I would advise to use absolute positioning). I will try to make a small example as answer :)

Comment: Hmm on second thought. I would advise you to use a datepicker library. This will be way easier to implement :)

Comment: That whole popup your screenshot shows, is generated completely by the browser. There is no way for you to manipulate how this renders. You _will_ need a custom solution for your requirement.

Comment: @Wimanicesir ok I see, I think I'm going with a library then. thx